# Problem with binding items to my collection view MAUI Andoid app

Tags: c#, maui

This is xaml:

```
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Wallpapers}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame Padding="2" Margin="2" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray">
                    <Image HeightRequest="700" Source="{Binding url}"/>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public Files Files { get; set; } = new();
    public Photo Photo { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Wallpaper> Wallpapers { get; set; } = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ContentPage_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string content;
        using (HttpClient client = new())
        {
            content = client.GetStringAsync("my link").Result;
        }
        Files = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Files>(content);

        
        Photo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Photo>(content);
        Wallpaper tmp = new()
        {
            url = Photo.result.GetLink()
        };
        Wallpapers.Add(tmp);
        //Categories.Add();
        //Uri = (UriImageSource)photo.result.GetLink();
        //DisplayAlert("asd", photo.result.GetLink(), "OK");
    }
}
```

Class "Wallpapers":

```
public class Wallpaper
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

So I've googled every possible mistake and there were no results as mine. I need to bind observable collection out of class "Wallpaper" to collection view. But when i try to bind it says "No DataContext found for Binding 'Wallpapers'" and nothing helps. MAUI Android App. So i need you to tell me what should i do?

Comment: Well, you have to set the DataContext for your Bindings

Comment: Did you adding "BindingContext = this" on MainPage() constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "**BindingContext = this**" on main page constructor

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is adding "BindingContext = this" on MainPage() constructor

Comment: if my comment solve your plobem plz i will post it as an answer, that help me a lot!